# Submit application Windos Store 404 not found logo

Tags: windows-store

I have developed an application for Windows Store,but when I press review button ,It doesn't display my logo(404 Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently when I uploaded/certified my first Windows Store application.  I discussed the problem with a Windows Representative, and they stated that it could take from 24 to 48 hours for the images to be displayed.

If you are still having issues with images after two days contact [Microsoft Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh690938)